# Are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4....... also considered Romaji?

Tags: numbers, rōmaji

Are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4....... also considered Romaji? If they are not written using kanji?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. ローマ字 (Roman script) is actually an alternative name for ラテン文字 (Latin script), which only refers to A, B, ..., Z. In Japanese, ローマ字 also means transcribing Japanese words using Latin alphabet, but that's an extension of the original meaning.

- A, B, C, ...: [Latin/Roman script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script) ラテン文字／ローマ(文)字
- 0, 1, 2, ...: [Arabic numeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) アラビア数字
- I, II, III, ...: [Roman numeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) ローマ数字